# How can use ImageView with 2 images in android to hide or show clip one of the 2 images?

Tags: android, xml, image, imageview, clip

I see that i can set 2 images in one ImageView in android using a  new Drawable XML file under resources, called for this example my2img.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img2" />
</layer-list>
```

and Apply to the imageView.

```
testimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.my2img));
```

But how can i access one of the 2 images from Java code ?
For example on runtime i want to show the first image full overlapped by a only a slice of the other image, another moment the full second image..and so on... just like a progress bar behaviour.

Is there any code sample ?

Comment: See LayerDrawable docs

Comment: i try this code but it doesent work:     ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) imageview.getDrawable();

    
final ClipDrawable d1 = (ClipDrawable) drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.lay1);

d1.setLevel(d1.getLevel() + 1000);

Comment: it throws an exception: 01-07 23:02:49.305: E/AndroidRuntime(4159): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable